# How to trigger a call to backend when opening the page - vue?

Tags: vue.js, jwt, token, vue-router

I need to make `vue` project where users are recognized by session, it is not possible to login. I don't know where to make `axios` call to backend in order to get `jwt` token.

If I put this `axios` call to `router/index.js`

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  if (to.meta.authRequired) {    
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

    if (!jwt) {
       this.$axios.get(`localhost:8081/api/users/jwtWithoutLogin`,{
        }).then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.jwt)

          });   
            
    }

    const payload = JSON.parse(atob(jwt.split('.')[1]));
    const username = payload.username
    localStorage.setItem("username", username)
  }

  next();
});
```

I got error `TypeError: _this is undefined`
I also tried variants with `self`, without `this` (but with imported `axios` plugin), it does not work.

I don't know if I'm on the right track. On which element this `axios` request could be made? I think it is absurdly to put button with this function, because it need to be done just on opening homepage, not clicking on button? But don't know what other to do?

Comment: There's not enough context to determine the problem. Show where your code is being used, so that we can determine what `this` is supposed to be. And how have you setup `$axios` in your project?

Comment: Yes, axios calls are working on other routes to backend.

Comment: Did you try to make axios call in mounted hook of home page?